# Ractive.js preventDefault events on event proxies

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

Lets say I have the following code:

**template**

```
<a on-click='myfunc' href="#">Activate!</button>
```

**javascript**

```
var ractive = new Ractive({
  el: output,
  template: template
});

ractive.on( 'myfunc', function ( event ) {
  alert( 'Hello world!' );
  ?????? --> how to prevent the next click event from the a href?
});
```

How can I prevent the next click event from the a href, from the javascript code?
I tried event.preventDefault(); but the object has no method 'preventDefault'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [docs](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/Ractive/wiki/Events):

```
event.original.preventDefault()
```

Proxy events are, as you've noticed, custom Ractive events; however, the `.original` property gets you access to the "real" event.

Comment: kudos for you. @Stephen Thomas